# Where id of object in list matches list of id set property to true

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list with pre-selected options.
I populate this list with a list of SelectListItems which allow you to set their "Selected" property to true.

However I want to set property to true if the select list item's value (id of option) matches a list of Id's of the options selected using linq.

I believe this gets each object that value matches the list of ID's, however I'm not sure how I now select each item and set their "Selected" property to true. I'm aware I could set this to a list then loop over the list set the values to true then return that list, but I'd prefer to do it on one line for simplicity if possible.

```
public List<SelectListItem> StorageFormats { get; set; }

StorageFormats = await _storageFormat.GetStorageFormatSelectList();

StorageFormats = StorageFormats
    .Where(x => _availabilityFormatMap
        .GetAvalabilityStorageFormat(id)
        .Select(y => y.ID)
        .ToString()
        .Contains(x.Value))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two ways to do this.

1. Through List.ForEach :-

```
StorageFormats.ForEach(x => x.Selected = true); 
// change it according to your class structure.
```

2. Through making an extension :-

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void SetSelectedForEach(this IEnumerable<StorageFormat> source, bool value)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            item.Selected = value;
        }
    }
}

// change according to your namespace and class structures.
```

and then use it like this.

```
StorageFormats.SetSelectedForEach(true);
```